# mutate filter did not working as expected

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

have some issue with mutate filter where cannot combine any value in the newly created field

here is the example of the code use

```
mutate {
add_field => {
  "myfield" => "%{OrderDate} %{BusinessMinute}"
}
```

output in kibana for this field is  %{OrderDate} %{BusinessMinute} where I'm expecting it is showing the value of this field

Comment: Are you sure the fields OrderDate & BusinessMinute exist at this point in the pipeline?

Comment: Hi, yes it is there. First things is i will extract all related data using grok and this is where this two field was define. After the grok match i add this condition but when i called this two field value it doesnt print me this two field value. Any idea ?

Comment: This is the correct usage, share your full pipeline and a sample of your data so people can try to see what is wrong and simulate it.

Comment: Hi @leandrojmp, ok this is my sample data in pipeline

"component_log_time" => 2020-03-03T06:28:29.844Z,
 "comb" => "8514"

even when i did this mutate filter to add new field for **comb** it will show me this output in kibana %{COMB} and not the value of **comb** which is supposed to be 8514

Comment: You are already using the `add_field` in the correct way, if it is not working, something is wrong in your pipeline, you need to share your **full** pipeline to show what is going on, not just snippets of it, share your inputs and filters. How are the field `comb` being generated? Field names are case sensitive, are you seeing `%{COMB}` or `%[comb}` in kibana?

Comment: its is showing %[comb} in kibana and not the value of this extracted field. Updated the details in aobve description.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for notifying me that %{COMB} and %{comb}. it works now as i somehow wrongly call COMB and in grok is comb !! thanks mate ! really appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

As per comments some case sensitive issue that I wrongly use